# Corrupt image with webcam on Raspberry Pi Zero and OpenCV

Tags: python, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, webcam

I attached a USB webcam to my Raspberry Pi Zero W though an OTG cable. When I run my python script the OpenCV video capture at first gave me select timeout errors:

```py
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
_, img = vs.read()
cv.imwrite(filename="image.jpg", img=img)
```

Then I tried:

```
rmmod uvcvideo
modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=5000 quirks=0x80
```

It doesn't give select timeout errors anymore but the image seems corrupt. Here is an output image from the webcam:

[image: image from webcame]

Comment: Looks to me that the horizontal resolution is set incorrectly somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it a while ago and I thought I should answer my own question:

```
vc.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 480)
vc.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 360)
```

I just had to tell CV the correct width and height of the camera.